# Delete Android Browser History of particular domain

Tags: android, dns, browser-history

I'm trying to develop an android application that could erase browser's history of the particular domain. For example, I want to delete the history of "google.co.in" domain.

But I can able delete all the browser history by using the following code.

**Added the following permissions to AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

**In my activity:**

```
Browser.clearHistory(getContentResolver());
```

How can I do it for a particular domain? Anybody help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**One aproach**

Use [Browser.deleteFromHistory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#deleteFromHistory(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String)).

Also take a look at Browser's private method [`getVisitedLike`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/provider/Browser.java) to find out how to filter urls. Instead of `History.CONTENT_URI` you should use `Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI`.

**Another aproach**

Another way is to delete directly from Content provider. Something like this:`getContentResolver().delete(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL + " like ?", myDomain + "%");`